# Pip config settings not working for virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, config, virtual-environment

Studying https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/ I understand that I can have multiple `pip.conf` files (on a UNIX-based system) which are loaded in the described order.

My task is to write a bash script that automatically creates a virtual environment and sets pip configuration only for the virtual environment.

```
# my_bash_script.sh
...
python -m virtualenv .myvenv
....
touch pip.conf
# this will create path/to/.myvenv/pip.conf
# otherwise following commands will be in the user's pip.conf at ~/.config/pip/pip.conf

path/to/.myvenv/bin/python -m pip config set global.proxy "my-company-proxy.com"
# setting our company proxy here

path/to/.myvenv/bin/python -m pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org" 
# because of SSL issues from behind the company's firewall I need this to make pip work
...
```

My problem is, that I want to set the configuration not for `global` but for `site`. If I exchange `global.proxy` and `global.trusted-host` for `site.proxy` and `site.trusted-host` pip won't be able to install packages anymore whereas everything works fine if I leave it at `global`. Also changing it to `install.proxy` and `install.trusted-host` doesn't work.

The pip.conf file looks like this afterwards:

```
# /path/to/.myvenv/pip.conf
[global]
proxy = "my-company-proxy.com"
trusted-host = "pypi.org pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org"
```

`pip config debug` yields the following:

```
env_var:
env:
global:
  /etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
  /etc/pip.conf, exists: False
site:
  /path/to/.myvenv/pip.conf, exists: True
    global.proxy: my-company-proxy.com
    global.trusted-host: pypi.org pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org
user:
  /path/to/myuser/.pip/pip.conf, exists: False
  /path/to/myuser/.config/pip/pip.conf, exists: True
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `[global]` in the config file refers to the fact that these settings are used for all pip commands. See [this section of the manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#per-command-section). So you can do something like

```
[global]
timeout = 60

[freeze]
timeout = 10
```

The `global/site` distinction comes from the location of the config file. So your file `/path/to/.myvenv/pip.conf` is referred to as the `site` config file through its location. In it, you still need to have

```
[global]
proxy = "my-company-proxy.com"
trusted-host = "pypi.org pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org"
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was thinking too. But I wonder why [install] + proxy/trusted-host fails then.

Comment: Does it work if you use global though?

Comment: Yes - like a charm - it's more like: I want to understand why it wouldn't work with [install] :-)